# HTTP Error 500 when attempting to access localhost

Tags: localhost

I just built my first "web app" for a class using Google App Engine, and it deployed correctly, and works perfectly well on Google's servers. However, when I try to access it on localhost, I get a 500 error:

"Server error The website encountered an error while retrieving http://localhost:8081/. It may be down for maintenance or configured incorrectly."

I have tried using various ports, and none of them seem to work. I am 100% positive I am using the correct port and that the app is actually running with no errors.

I am using Google Chrome and Python 2.7.2 on Mac OS 10.6.8

Any ideas on how to correct this or what configurations to check?

Comment: @Wooble they mentioned that GAE was using Python 2.6, which I found strange, because if I run Python in Terminal, 2.7 is automatically launched. I'm still getting the following warnings though:
<br>
The rdbms API is not available because the MySQLdb library could not be loaded.<br>
 Could not read datastore data from /var/folders/pY/pYpXP3FPE8OrVeLQryckbU+++TI/-Tmp-/dev_appserver.datastore<br>
 Could not initialize images API; you are likely missing the Python "PIL" module. ImportError: No module named _imaging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out, the issue was that GAE was accessing an older version of python on my computer.

I was able to fix this by opening up the python launcher, copying the path from "Interpreter", and pasting it into GAE under Preferences/Python Path. In my case, the correct path is /usr/local/bin/pythonw

It is important to note that as there is no "ok" or "apply" button here, you must hit enter to apply the path change.

Answer (score 0):

"Error 500" is generic for "I asked the server to do something, and it failed".

1) Look in your web server's error logs

2) Debug your "hello world" application

ALSO:

3) Make sure you can run this "hello world":

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/helloworld

4) If you can't, then review the setup instructions here:

http://googcloudlabs.appspot.com/setup.html